# ActiveMQ 5.9 startup script?

Tags: linux, activemq-classic, startup, aix

I was looking at the startup script for ActiveMQ at http://activemq.apache.org/unix-service.html, but I realise that this is for version 4 of ActiveMQ, and the scripts seem to have changed a lot since then.

Was wondering if someone could share how to autostart ActiveMQ 5.9 on server startup?
We are running on AIX 7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ActiveMQ uses the Java Service Wrapper to run the broker](http://activemq.apache.org/java-service-wrapper.html).

You can easily configure Wrapper to be launched as a [*nix service](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/launch-nix-boot-debian.html). (and AIX is Unix, hopefully)

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I've missed this part!

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS or Redhat:

```
systemctl enable activemq
```